# How can I use value of select the right way if the Node = X and I need an information from the folder where Node = X is in

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with selecting a value from an node. I want to select the information stored in cac:item/cbc:name from the InvoiceLine with ID 2. I can't seem to use value of select in the right way, because it always gets the answer from the first node, the one with ID 1 in InvoiceLince. Can somebody please help me out with selecting the value stored in cac:item/cbc:name from the InvoiceLine with ID 2?

```
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>1</ID>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">0</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>S</ID>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Name>
Relatienaam:    : BLABLA
Bezoekadres : BLABLA2
</Name>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0</PriceAmount>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
<ID>2</ID>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">0</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxTotal>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
<TaxSubtotal>
<TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxableAmount>
<TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
<TaxCategory>
<ID>S</ID>
<Percent>0</Percent>
<TaxScheme>
<ID>VAT</ID>
</TaxScheme>
</TaxCategory>
</TaxSubtotal>
</TaxTotal>
<Item>
<Name>685000/06.0009/7603/355132.01</Name>
</Item>
<Price>
<PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0</PriceAmount>
</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
```

I have already tried the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice/InvoiceLine/ID[ID='2']">
      <xsl:if test="."><xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(cbc:Name,' ',''),1,6)"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I expect the output of 685000 and not Relati. Am i doing something wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `/x:Invoice/InvoiceLine/ID[ID='2']`

It will find another `ID` element under `<ID>`, I am not sure if it gives you error or any wrong output (based on your description)

I am assuming your input without namespaces for now as it is not mentioned in the question.

Try this out: (Modify it to add up the namespaces or modify the question itself)

**Assumed Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice>
<InvoiceLine>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">0
    </LineExtensionAmount>
    <TaxTotal>
        <TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
        <TaxSubtotal>
            <TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxableAmount>
            <TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
            <TaxCategory>
                <ID>S</ID>
                <Percent>0</Percent>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <ID>VAT</ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </TaxCategory>
        </TaxSubtotal>
    </TaxTotal>
    <Item>
        <Name>
            Relatienaam: : BLABLA
            Bezoekadres : BLABLA2
        </Name>
    </Item>
    <Price>
        <PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0</PriceAmount>
    </Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">0
    </LineExtensionAmount>
    <TaxTotal>
        <TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
        <TaxSubtotal>
            <TaxableAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxableAmount>
            <TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">0</TaxAmount>
            <TaxCategory>
                <ID>S</ID>
                <Percent>0</Percent>
                <TaxScheme>
                    <ID>VAT</ID>
                </TaxScheme>
            </TaxCategory>
        </TaxSubtotal>
    </TaxTotal>
    <Item>
        <Name>685000/06.0009/7603/355132.01</Name>
    </Item>
    <Price>
        <PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">0</PriceAmount>
    </Price>
</InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

**Solution can be:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Invoice/InvoiceLine">
        <xsl:if test="ID ='2'">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(Item/Name,' ',''),1,6)" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Find the demo here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6x

Comment: Thank you Vebbie! It shows the correct uitcome (the line in cbc:Name of the InvoiceLine where the ID = 2). THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

The expression you (probably) want is this...

```
/x:Invoice/InvoiceLine[ID='2']
```

Currently, by doing `/x:Invoice/InvoiceLine/ID[ID='2']`, you are selecting the `ID` element itself, but then only if that `ID` has a child `ID` of 2 (which it doesn't).

By doing `/x:Invoice/InvoiceLine[ID='2']` you are selecting the `InvoiceLine` element, and so the relative expression `cbc:Name` should then also return something.

Do note, this assumes you are handling namespaces correctly, as you have not actually shown any namespace declarations in your XML.

(Note, if you did want to select the `ID` element, you would write `/x:Invoice/InvoiceLine/ID[.='2']`, but to then  get the `name` you would need to do `../cbc:name`, where `..` is used to get the parent of the current node)